# MySQL: Select from multiple tables with field to show which table the record came from

Tags: mysql, sql, union, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables which contain very similar information. The tables are owners, managers, and employees. I am trying to pull information from all 3 tables, while still understanding which table each record came from. I also do not want duplicates. All tables have an email_id which relates to an `email` table which I am joining.

Also, it is very likely that the email_id will exist in multiple tables (i.e. An email could be an owner and manager, or all 3 even).

Here is what I have thus far:

```
SELECT email
FROM (
    (
        SELECT e.email
        FROM `owners` as o
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = o.email_id
        WHERE o.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT e.email
        FROM `managers` as m
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = m.email_id
        WHERE m.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT e.email
        FROM `employees` as emp
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = emp.email_id
        WHERE v.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    )
) as `people`
ORDER BY email ASC
```

This query actually works perfectly. It removes duplicates from the tables individually, but keeps them across multiple tables. I still have no way to know which table each comes from. I tried to modify the query to this:

```
SELECT email, owner, manager, employee
FROM (
    (
        SELECT e.email, 'yes' as owner
        FROM `owners` as o
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = o.email_id
        WHERE o.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT e.email, 'yes' as manager
        FROM `managers` as m
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = m.email_id
        WHERE m.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT e.email, 'yes' as employee
        FROM `employees` as emp
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = emp.email_id
        WHERE v.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    )
) as `people`
ORDER BY email ASC
```

This did not work because not all tables had the same columns. If I add all fields to all tables (i.e. `SELECT e.email, 'yes' as owner, '' as manager, '' as employee`) the query works, but all tables seem to have the same field. Not sure why.

Ultimately, I would like to have no duplicate email addresses in the returned record set, and have each record something like `email = 'email address', owner = 'yes/no', manager = 'yes/no', employee = 'yes/no'`.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? If you need further information, just comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "table_name" column to each set of results to identify which table the results came from

```
(
    SELECT e.email, 'owners' as table_name
    FROM `owners` as o
    LEFT JOIN `email` as e
    ON e.email_id = o.email_id
    WHERE o.company_id = 3
    GROUP BY e.email
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT e.email, 'managers' as table_name
    FROM `managers` as m
    LEFT JOIN `email` as e
    ON e.email_id = m.email_id
    WHERE m.company_id = 3
    GROUP BY e.email
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT e.email, 'employees' as table_name
    FROM `employees` as emp
    LEFT JOIN `email` as e
    ON e.email_id = emp.email_id
    WHERE v.company_id = 3
    GROUP BY e.email
)
```

Alternatively add 3 columns to each block of results. i.e. add *is_owner, is_manager, is_employee* to *all* 3 select blocks

Comment: Alternatively add 3 columns to each block of results. i.e. add *is_owner, is_manager, is_employee* to *all* 3 select blocks

Comment: And you can even remove the parentheses!

Comment: I have actually tried to add 3 columns to each block of results and it is not working correctly. Can you show an example of this?

Comment: Actually, I got this to work. However, Is there anyway to group the results and maintain the columns? For example, currently 2 records have the same email address, one being is_owner and the other having is_manager. Any way to consolidate these and have both is_owner and is_manager there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by forcing a value in each row this way:

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, 'YourFirstTable' as fromTable from t1
union all
select t2.field1, t2.field2, 'YourSecondTable' from t2
```

If you want to remove duplicates from the whole result set (where by "removing duplicates" I understand you want the email from **any** of the tables) you should wrap that in an outer query and apply a group by:

```
select field1, field2, max(fromTable)
    select t1.field1 as field1, t1.field2 as field2, 'YourFirstTable' as fromTable from t1
    union all
    select t2.field1, t2.field2, 'YourSecondTable' from t2
group by field1, field2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT e.email,"owners" AS people
        FROM `owners` as o
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = o.email_id
        WHERE o.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
     UNION ALL
        SELECT e.email,"managers" AS people
        FROM `managers` as m
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = m.email_id
        WHERE m.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email
    UNION ALL
        SELECT e.email,"employees" AS people
        FROM `employees` as emp
        LEFT JOIN `email` as e
        ON e.email_id = emp.email_id
        WHERE v.company_id = 3
        GROUP BY e.email;
```